# Monitors wake immediately after they are put to sleep automatically

Tags: multiple-monitors, 20.04, acpi, wakeup, idle

Basically I have it set to blank my monitors after 5 minutes idle, which it will do, monitors will show the(monitor side) `Going into standby mode, no source` message, go black and then wake about 10 seconds later. This is not from any (real)mouse movement or KB presses.

I've tried viewing whats capable of waking from `/proc/acpi/wakeup` with no luck as I have 0 idea what the 4 letter codes for the enabled devices mean. Any help on figuring out which device is causing this would be greatly appreciated.

contents of file `/proc/acpi/wakeup` are:

```
GPP0      S4    *disabled
GPP0      S4    *disabled
GPP1      S4    *disabled
GPP3      S4    *disabled
GPP4      S4    *disabled
GPP5      S4    *disabled
GPP6      S4    *disabled
GPP7      S4    *disabled
GPP8      S4    *disabled
X161      S4    *disabled
GPP9      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:03.2
X162      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:08:00.0
GPPA      S4    *disabled
GPPB      S4    *disabled
GPPC      S4    *disabled
GPPD      S4    *disabled
GPPE      S4    *disabled
GPPF      S4    *disabled
GP17      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:07.1
XHC0      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:09:00.3
GP18      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:08.1
PS2K      S3    *disabled
PS2M      S3    *disabled
UAR1      S4    *disabled  pnp:00:03
GPP2      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:01.3
X4_0      S4    *disabled
X4_1      S4    *disabled
X411      S4    *disabled
X413      S4    *disabled
AS42      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:04:00.0
X412      S4    *disabled
I211      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:06:00.0
PTXH      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:01:00.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I have this issue on a laptop and it was the USB keyboard or mouse that was causing the wakeup. I had to issue the following for me to disable wakeup for my USB devices:

```
sudo -s
echo XHC > /proc/acpi/wakeup
echo EHC1 > /proc/acpi/wakeup
echo EHC2 > /proc/acpi/wakeup
```

And I added those commands to /etc/rc.local as otherwise the state was not permanent.

I see you don't have either XHC or any EHC named devices but you do have XHC0 which may be a USB device.

Only drawback for me is of course now I can't use the USB keyboard to wake the laptop at all.

Comment: sadly still no dice :/ I may just go through and try to eliminate those one by one to see if anything changes. Just hoping someone had more luck than myself with this... Been an issue for a little over a year, just now getting the chance to actually look into it haha

thanks for the help anyways!

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem,
it has nothing to do with /proc/acpi/wakeup, I disabled all without result

The problem was my new Lenovo monitor, I disabled the auto-switching of the source of the monitor,
Now the monitor is running with HDMI only and my (K)Ubuntu 21.10 keeps in power-save
Maybe somebody can explain it to me :)